# How to get top 2 customers from customer table using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

In customer table:

```
ID|   Name   |   Cost
-------------------------
 1|   name1  |   1000
 2|   name2  |   200 
 3|   name3  |   700 
 4|   name2  |   700 
 5|   name3  |   800
```

I need to find out Top 2 customers name & ID & cost from customer table who buy .
Can anyone help me ?

My expected Output :

```
ID|   Name   |   Cost
----------------------
 1|   name1  |   1000
 2|   name2  |   900
```

Comment: use `group by.. order by .. limit`.

Comment: This seems like a fairly simple thing to do? maybe you should try and learn the basics of MySQL a bit better? What have you tried so far?

Comment: ID is meaningless in your result

Comment: Just take and accept my answer :D Its only MySQL basics, so I believe you don't want to learn MySQL language and just know the result :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(ID) as payment_ids, 
    Name, 
    SUM(Cost) as total_cost 
FROM 
    Customer 
GROUP BY 
    Name 
ORDER BY 
    total_cost DESC 
LIMIT 2
```